# Add access control origin header information across multisite

Tags: multisite, headers, user-access

I want to add the below snippet to my wordpress installation.

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");?>
```

I don't want to add it in every template header as there are many of them and I have 60 networks with 2-3 sites in each network. In what file should I add this snippet so that it has effect across the entire wordpress installation?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to do this at web server level.

If you are on NGINX server, you can use in your site conf file:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

If you are on Apache server, you can use in your .htaccess:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```